# Ionic 2: Http.get() run function for each row in response results with Rx

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, ionic2, map-function

**Q) How can I run a function (e.g: one that adds the id of each item to the end of the title) for each row of the results in this call?**

Assume that my response below is something like:

```
[
  { id: 1. title: 'first', completed: 1 },
  { id: 2. title: 'second', completed: 1 },
  { id: 3. title: 'third', completed: 1 }
]
```

My getTodos code:

```
return this._http.get(url, {
  headers: headers
}).map(res => <Todo[]>res.json());
```

My Todo interface:

```
export interface Todo {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}
```

My example function I'd like to run on each response row:

```
function addToTitle(item) {
  item.title += " " + item.id;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add another `map` operator using the `map` function of arrays:

```
return this._http.get(url, {
  headers: headers
}).map(res => <Todo[]>res.json())
.map((todos) => {
  todos.forEach((todo) => {
    todo.title += ' ' + todo.id;
  });
  return todos;
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't actually ever return, becomes void!

Comment: What do you mean by "becomes void"? You don't receive the data when subscribing on the returned observable.

Comment: Yeah exactly. The method doesn't return. Void.

Comment: Oh! Yes, you're right. `forEach` returns void. You need to return `todos` instead. I updated my answer...